# Opening a web site in a container within an html page

Tags: css, html, iframe, webview

I am basically trying to put an html frame within another html page. I tried to open the below site using iframe but no help. Please help me to open this site and also other ways apart from iframe to do this, also I wish to rewrite the html script later in R, so please suggest the suitable approach to follow. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<base target="_blank">
<iframe>
src="google.com" height="200" width="300"
</iframe>
</body></html>
```

**Update**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
 <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_parent"><button>Click me !
  </button></a>
</body></html>
```

Comment: @vaishalikapadia, I kindly request you to edit the statement as my requirement is to fit a web page within an iframe or a suitable container which is a part of existing html page, not an html page within an html page.

Comment: yeah right.. deleted

Comment: @vaishalikapadia, Thanks.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. `<iframe src=""></iframe>` Read more here --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: Do you want to embed google.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example how **syntax** for `iframe` looks.

```
 <iframe  width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.google.co.za/" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" allowfullscreen>
 </iframe>
```

cant be implemented correctly since google not allowed in frame.

This would work for example :

```
 <iframe  width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.rdocumentation.org/" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" allowfullscreen>
 </iframe>
```

**R** syntax:

```
iframe(width, height, url_link) //syntax

iframe(width = "560", height = "315", url_link = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/0fKg7e37bQE") //example
```

Here is the **R** documentation.
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyLP/versions/1.1.0/topics/iframe

**EXTRA**

Read this about adding custom search from google [Click Me](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2641279)

**Implementing any fully functional website**

To use the `iframe` in full perspective of the browser ill give you an example using your code:

Also included an button tag to open and close iframe.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".btn").click(function() {
  $("#frame").toggle();
 });
});
```

```css
.btn {color: black; background-color: #eee; height: 50px; width: 200px; border-radius: 10px;border-color: #96bdd9;box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #f4f8fb; margin-bottom: 20px;outline: none;}
.test {position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.test iframe { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button class="btn" >Iframe Open & close</button>

<div class="test">
  <iframe id="frame" style="display: none;" width="100%" src="https://getbootstrap.com/" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto">
  </iframe>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, would really appreciate if you can embed your code with mine above and give a complete script such that I can try it.

Comment: @AdamShaw i amended my awnser have a look

Comment: I really really appreciate your efforts Sir, this rdocumentation is a great one. However, when I embed this, the functionality that I can achieve if I open the site in a browser is way more than this. From a learner's perspective, I just want to know, is there a possibility of implementing any fully functional website in a container like an iframe in html such that I can use it fully like how I use in a browser.

Comment: if i understood correctly look at my updated answer and let me know if its what you want @AdamShaw

Comment: thanks but I am not able to run it, my main concern however is that can we embed a fully functional website within another web page in html like your "rdocumentation" that you helped me with?

Comment: yess , as shown above its fully functional within that `iframe` , you must be able to run that and see the example , in what browser are you working on??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163415/discussion-between-adam-shaw-and-ylama).

Comment: please help me with this post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499963/make-the-first-element-of-a-selectinput-in-r-shiny-appear-bold/48500479#48500479

Answer (score 0):

**You can’t show Google in an iframe.**

You also can’t show Yahoo!, Twitter or Facebook in an iframe.

Most major sites and banks block this ability through the use of

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

Read more here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options