# Make the first element of a selectInput in R shiny appear bold

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I wish to make the first element "1" of the selectInput bold in color. Please help.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
selectInput(
"select",
label = h3("Select box"),
choices = c(1,2,3,4)
))
server <- function(input, output) {
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the style as suggested by **@Nitin Shinde** in your shiny app like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$head(tags$style(".option:first-child{
    font-weight:bold;
    //color:#ff0000;
  }")),
  selectInput(
    "select",
    label = h3("Select box"),
    choices = c(1,2,3,4)
  ))
server <- function(input, output) {
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The output would be something like this:

[image]

Comment: this is good, but if there are multiple selectInputs, then I see the first element of all the selectInputs colour black, can you help me in applying the change to only the first particular selectInput? Kindly check the edit

Comment: as first-child property references the first element in a selectInput, similarly, which propertly will reference the first value of the second or third selectInput, kindly help?

Comment: I have done some study and came up with this css tag which actually works on html select tags, select:nth-child(4) option:first-child{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000000;
    } please help me to fit this within R.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `shinyWidgets` package which has a lot of cool features with its `pickerInput`

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput(inputId = "Id069", 
              label = "Style individual options with HTML", 
              choices = c("steelblue 150%", 
                          "right align + red", "bold", 
                          "background color"), choicesOpt = list(style = c("color: steelblue; font-size: 150%;", 
                                                                           "color: firebrick; text-align: right;", 
                                                                           "font-weight: bold;", "background: forestgreen; color: white;")))

  )
server <- function(input, output) {
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: thanks, but I have furthur dependancy on selectInput, please help me to only make the first element of the selectInput bold only, thanks.

Comment: Please check the edit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48501999/highlighting-the-initial-element-of-a-specific-selectinput-in-r-shiny

Comment: `shinyWidgets` package has the feature you need, instead of using `selectInput` use `pickerInput`. If I give you the answer you wont learn anything

Comment: I have been finding a fix since ages, there is a reason I am not using pickerInput, as this requirement is a part of a much larger requirement, look and feel perspective also needs to be checked, check this link, the solution has a fix in html, however I wish to covert the same in R https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514038/css-attribute-to-access-a-specific-selectinput-and-make-the-initial-element-bold/48514133#48514133 . Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pseudo elements in CSS

```
<style>
    option:first-child{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ff0000;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: thanks for replying here, but I need to embed this in R, please help?

Comment: If I have multiple selectInputs, how should I access the first child of a specific input then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below and nest each selectInput inside the div with class = "test" for every one you wish the first item to be bold in.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$head(tags$style(".test .option:first-child{
                       font-weight:bold;
                       //color:#ff0000;
                       }")),
  div(class = "test",selectInput(
    "select",
    label = h3("Select box"),
    choices = c(1,2,3,4)
  )),
  selectInput(
    "select2",
    label = h3("Select box"),
    choices = c(1,2,3,4)
  )

  )
server <- function(input, output) {
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You can set the class of the div to whatever you like just be sure to change the .test part of the CSS accordingly.

Updating "//color:#ff0000;" to "color:#ff0000;" will change the colour to red, just update the hex code to whichever colour you would like to use.