# Css attribute to access a specific selectInput and make the initial element bold

Tags: html, css, shiny, shinydashboard

the given html script creates three selectInputs and updates the first element of all the three selectInputs black and bold. I just want to make the change to the third selectInput Box and not the other two. Please help me with an appropriate css attribute to achieve this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
option:first-child{
font-weight:bold;
color:#000000;
}
</style>
<select>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
<select>
<option value="a1">Volvo1</option>
<option value="a2">Saab1</option>
</select>
<select>
<option value="v1">Volvo2</option>
<option value="v2">Saab2</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: SelectBox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **nth-child** in css to select particular select tag and make its first option as bold like u did.

```
select:nth-child(3) option:first-child{
font-weight:bold;
color:#000000;
}
```

see the codepen below

[See this pen](https://codepen.io/saikiranmarripati/pen/bLGPWK)

Comment: thanks, it works perfectly, however I have an addon dependancy to utilize this script in R shiny, please check this link if you can help me with a tweak here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48501999/highlighting-the-initial-element-of-a-specific-selectinput-in-r-shiny

Answer (score 0):

Give the third select a class.

```
<select class="third">
<option value="v1">Volvo2</option>
<option value="v2">Saab2</option>
</select>
```

edit css:

```
.third option:first-child{
font-weight:bold;
color:#000000;
}
```